# Java sorting a Pojo using comparable

Tags: java

The output of the following program is not what I expected it to come. What is wrong in this program? Please suggest.

[Hello113 
, Hello380 
, Hello293 
, Hello290 
, Hello246 
, Hello456 
, Hello797 
, Hello888 
, Hello981 
]

**EDIT**: I wanted to do this in this way only. Not using collections.sort().

```
   public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random(10);

        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            Employee e = new Employee(i,"Hello"+random.nextInt(1000));
            employees.add(e);
        }
        System.out.println(employees);
    }

    }

    class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>
    {
    private int empNo;
    private String empName;

    public int getEmpNo() {
        return empNo;
    }
    public void setEmpNo(int empNo) {
        this.empNo = empNo;
    }
    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }
    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }

    Employee(int empNo,String empName)
    {
        this.empName=empName;
        this.empNo=empNo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return empName+" \n";
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee o) {

        return this.getEmpName().compareTo(o.getEmpName());
    }
```

}

Comment: you never actually sort the list ...

Comment: I updated my answer also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ArrayList` keeps the order of the elements as you added them. If you want to sort them you need either to create a sorting method that will use the `compareTo` that you implemented, or simply you can call `Collections.sort(employees)`.

I recommend to use your own implementation of a sorting algorithm. You could try to use `insertion sort` or `quicksort` and in this way you would get full use of not using something already implemented (as Collections.sort).

Also you could use `TreeSet` to have the collection sorted automatically but, being a `Set` you won't have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to sort them

```
Collections.sort(employees);
System.out.println(employees);
```

The method `Collections.sort()` will implicitly work out with `compareTo` method to sort the `Employee` objects.

The collection `ArrayList` is just an ordered collection and not sorted. So you need to sort it explicitly

If you want to sort without using `Collections.sort`, you will have to create a `TreeSet` and add the elements to it and then convert `TreeSet` to `ArrayList`

```
Set<Employee> employeeSet = new TreeSet<Employee>(employees);
List<Employee> sortedList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
sortedList.addAll(employeeSet);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use Collections.sort to sort the ArrayList, or use a TreeSet instead of an ArrayList, which will sort while you insert.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Set<Employee> employees = new TreeSet<Employee>();` instead of  `List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>()`;

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding compareTo method. So to use your implementation by default, you should use collections like `TreeSet` or `TreeMap`. To sort a arraylist, you will have to use `Collections.sort()`.

Other thing is implementation of your method is wrong for what you want to achieve. It should be

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Employee o) {
String first = this.getEmpName().append(String.valueOf(this.empNo);
String second= o.getEmpName().append(String.valueOf(o.empNo);
    return (first ).compareTo(second);
}
```